# Possible to run all handlers for a policy in-line instead of with an attribute?

Tags: c#, .net, authorization, .net-2.0

On most of my APIs, I simply do authorization like this:

```
[Authorize(Policy = "Foo")]
public MyApi()
```

I get this policy from a NuGet though and can't modify it.

For some of my APIs, I don't always want to have this policy. This needs to get figured out at runtime based on some config. I'd like some way to run this in-line, and ensure all the handlers that are setup run.

After a lot of searching i've found that I create an `IAuthorizationService`, and use that to call `AuthorizeAsync`. This seems like it's what I want, but the issue i'm running into now is that all the handlers rely on an `AuthorizationFilterContext` as the resource on the context. This seems to happen automatically when the Authorization is done through the attribute, but not through the call to AuthorizeAsync. It needs to be passed in manually in this case. My code right now looks like this:

```
public MyApi()
{
    var allowed = await _authorizationService.AuthorizeAsync(User, null, "Foo").ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

This seems to go through all my handlers correctly, but they don't work due to missing the `AuthorizationFilterContext`.

1) Is this the correct approach to begin with, or is there some other way to do this in-line? I'm guessing there's probably some way to create my own policy that wraps this one and I can check the config there, but if there's a simple in-line approach i'd prefer that.

2) If this way is valid, is there a good way to get the `AuthorizationFilterContext`? I've tried creating it manually, but i'm afraid this isn't actually correct without passing in more data from the context, but I can't find any good examples/doc:

`new AuthorizationFilterContext(new ActionContext(HttpContext, HttpContext.GetRouteData(), new ActionDescriptor()), new IFilterMetadata[] { });`

Comment: This is a really bad way to do it. First of all, any call can hit your api method now even though they dont have an access for it because you do the access check at later point. Create a custom attribute for yourself and you can easily check whatever the policy (either single or multiple) you want to check is owned by the user or not.Also good to read this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/iauthorizationpolicyprovider?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Answer (score -2):

There will be no `AuthorizationFilterContext` when you are outside of the authorization pipeline. You should therefore not handle the authentication inline with `IAuthorizationService`.

> This seems to go through all my handlers correctly, but they don't work due to missing the `AuthorizationFilterContext`.

Sounds like you have the control over the authentication handlers. Have you tried short-circuit authentication inside the handler if it is not required?

The handler can get services via the DI so you can put your required runtime config via *IOptions* or *IHttpContextAccessor* and what so ever.

Answer (score -2):

Can't you create you own `Authorize` attribute which would inherit current one and resolve policy internally? Or even better try using `IAuthorizationPolicyProvider`

```
class MyPolicyProvider : IAuthorizationPolicyProvider
{
    private DefaultAuthorizationPolicyProvider BackupPolicyProvider { get; }

    public MyPolicyProvider()
    {
        BackupPolicyProvider = new DefaultAuthorizationPolicyProvider(options);
    }

    public Task<AuthorizationPolicy> GetPolicyAsync(string policyName)
    {
        if (policyName.Equals("Foo"))
        {
            bool myConditionToAvoidPolicy = true;
            if (myConditionToAvoidPolicy)
            {
                return Task.FromResult<AuthorizationPolicy>(null);
            }
        }

        return BackupPolicyProvider.GetPolicyAsync(policyName);
    }
}
```

This is not tested, but you can find more about it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/iauthorizationpolicyprovider?view=aspnetcore-2.0#custom-iauthorizationpolicyprovider).

Answer (score -2):

Your check condition looks like happening at later point which I dont think it is a good idea. Your api method is being vulnerable and still open as your check is done at later point. But by using attribute you can capture it at earlier level and still can apply the custom logic. At the end of the day, all it decides is either "yes, have an access", or "no, no access for you!!" Below is not tested but should get you going:

```
public class CustomAuthorize : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    private readonly PermissionAction[] permissionActions;

    public CustomAuthorize(PermissionItem item, params PermissionAction[] permissionActions)
    {
        this.permissionActions = permissionActions;
    }

    public override void OnAuthorization(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        var currentIdentity = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity;
        if (!currentIdentity.IsAuthenticated) {
            // no access
        }

        bool myCondition = "money" == "happiness"; 
        if(myCondition){
           // do your magic here...
        }
        else{
          // another magic...
       }           
    }
}
```